# Container in Bootstrap 3 that perfectly adapts to the HEIGHT of the viewers' screen size

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, containers, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is the problem.

I use `bootstrap 3.0` for a very, very basic website. Still, I would like to add some refinement but I need help.

The structure of the website is very basic: a `container` and several `jumbotrons` inside the container.

I would like to have EACH Jumbotron to perfectly stretch to the height of the user's browser window, so that whatever the media may be (smartphone, web, etc) a visitor will see **ENTIRELY and ONLY** one jumbotron at the time without the need of scrolling down with the mouse...

Do you have an idea?
Many thanks!! ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could add a `special` CSS class to the container and set it to 100% height. The HTML and BODY must also be 100% height...

```
html,body {height:100%;}
.special,.special .jumbotron {height:100%;}
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/80826

This however does not address the issue of seeing only 1 jumbotron at a time.. which is more of a navigation issue than a size issue. You may want to use a carousel for the jumbotrons if you don't want the user to scroll down at all.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is actually stacking, full-screen, responsive backgrounds, or stacking divs that conform to the height of the window / viewport.

That's been answered over here:

[Full-screen responsive background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16548338/full-screen-responsive-background-image/19459998#19459998)