# Image background not showing for responsive div

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, background-image

It's a very simple and straightforward code:

HTML markup:

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center top-jumbotron">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.top-jumbotron {
    background: #ffcc00;
    background-image: url('../../bootstrap/img/home-page-banner.jpg');
    background-size: 100% auto;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: none;
}
```

My image is 2880px wide and shows just fine if I specify the width in px in the CSS. However, I am wary of using hard-coded metrics because I need the div to scale across all displays from mobile to Retina. Is there any way to make the image show up while using a percentage dimension for background-size? I don't want to use the `<img>` tag in HTML because I will be superimposing some text and other elements over the div; hence the background.

Comment: No more background image questions please. Check your answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/23970033/2884831

Comment: Tony Wu: I would love to not ask a question if the solutions offered already worked. Why should I have to use plugins or JS for something that should already be possible using plain CSS? And yes, I have tried all possible plain-CSS solutions provided with no success before posting the question. Thank you for your help though.

Answer (score 1):

Change `background-size: 100% auto;` to `background-size: cover;`. This will fill the div with the background image.

To center the image use `background-position: center;`

If you want the entire image within the div you can try `background-size: contain;` but this will leave empty areas in the div depending on it's size. You may also want to use `background-repeat: no-repeat;` when using `contain` to stop tiling.

Also I'm guessing you're specifying the height somewhere else in the css? Otherwise that will need to be added too.

[Here's a working example.](http://codepen.io/chrispollock/pen/wKamMG)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `background-position` attribute in your CSS?

Try:

```
.top-jumbotron {
    background: #ffcc00;
    background-image: url('../../bootstrap/img/home-page-banner.jpg');
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-position: center center; /*Add this*/
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't display anything. It does however, when I use a px value instead of % for background-size which is what I mentioned in the question as well.