# How to make a background image responsive

Tags: html, css

I just created a simple coming soon page with a background-image using css:

```
body{
   background-image: url(FreeVector-Fresh-Beer.jpg);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;  
}
```

Here the html:

```
<figure>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="Craft-Beer-SA-min.png" alt="Chania">
</figure>
<div class="paragraph" style="font-size:50px">
    <p>Our Website Is Brewing ! ! ! </p>
    <p>Coming To A Browser Near You. . .<br><a href="">info@craftbeersa.co.uk</a></p>           
</div>
```

How can I make this background image responsive?

Comment: Responsive in what context?Is it viewing of images on different screens or applying animations?

Comment: When you search on Google: `reposnsive background image full screen` you get [this](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/). Please search before you ask.

Comment: try google or a search engine of your choice. StackOverflow search should do as well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Full-screen responsive background image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16548338/full-screen-responsive-background-image)

Comment: @Elton Sousa : try background-size:100% 100vh;

Answer (score 2):

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>CraftBeerSa</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="text">
        <img src="Craft-Beer-SA-min.png" alt="">
        <div class="info">
            <p>WEBSITE COMING SOON</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    background-image: url(FreeVector-Fresh-Beer.jpg);
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    -wekit-background-attachment: fixed;
    -o-background-attachment: fixed;
    -moz-background-attachment: fixed;
}
.text{
    text-align:center;
}
img{
    margin-top:10%
}
.info{
    margin-top: 5%;
}
div p{
    font-size:5vw;
    color:#996633;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){
    .text img{
        width:100%;
    }
    img{
    margin-top:50%
    }
    .info{
        margin-top: 10%;
    }   
}
```

This solves absolutely everything.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`background-size:100% auto;`

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention what  I tried before.The background-size:100% only works for the width.

Comment: So image height is your problem?

Comment: Yes. Apparently  background-size:100% is better for the width though.
Just the height. I can see that is not 100%. part of the image is hidden  and I only see it in medium screens. Then in small screens,the image height does not cover the entire screen.

Comment: You have to use the media queries   `@media only screen and (max-width:767px)` ... This one is for mobile screens... Use height value in pixels.. Ex.. `height:300px;` .. It doesn't work means use `max-height`...

Answer (score 0):

```
body{    
    background: #222 url('FreeVector-Fresh-Beer.jpg') center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
}
```

---

Try the above code.

Comment: It works for the height. But I see that  in small screens it hides the image content in terms of width.

Comment: @EltonSousa It happens in coming soon pages, you can refer yourself http://webthemez.com/demo/coming-soon-responsive-web-template-trendset/ and http://bootstraptaste.com/demo/themes/WeBuild/

Answer (score 0):

You can directly apply your background to the `html` element and use `background-size: cover` to assure it covers the whole area leaving no gap.

```
html { 
  background: #222 url('FreeVector-Fresh-Beer.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Otherwise, you can make sure you declare `height: 100%` on your body tag, so body takes the full height of the browser too and apply the background there instead.

```
body { 
  background: #222 url('FreeVector-Fresh-Beer.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
}
```

`Background-size: cover` assures that the whole will be covered without expanding or stretching your image; naturally that means parts of your image will be hidden. However, if you want to simply expand it, that is, stretch it, to take the full area, you may use `background-size: 100% 100%`.

In general you want to use `cover` and you may decide what area remains visible through `background-position` (which is center, center) on my answer in the shorthand property (so you always would see the center, vertically and horizontally) but it could be:

1. Horizontally: left | right | center
2. Vertically: top | bottom | center

Comment: .It works for the height. But I see that  in small screens it hides the image content in terms of width.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Naturally if you don't stretch it, your image will need to get cropped which means some areas will be no longer visible. You can control that through background-position values.