# full img size in any screen size

Tags: html, css, styles

When I run my code in my laptop, then the img is showin full screen. But when I run it on a bigger screen size then it comes double: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMMLQ.jpg)

This is my css code I use:

```
body {

  background: url(pic.jpg); 
  background-size: cover;  
  background-position: center;
  font-family: Lato;
  color: white;
}


html {
height: 100%
}
```

Can someone help me fix the issue, that the img should go full screen on any screen size?

Comment: whats your html?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Full-screen responsive background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16548338/full-screen-responsive-background-image)

Comment: try `background-repeat: no-repeat;`

Comment: @zenubeh whether the below answer helped?

Comment: @AravindS this doesn0t work. When the screen is finished, then it shows me a white bar.

Comment: @aMJay see below

Comment: yes of course since we gave #fff in the background...did you added `background-size: 100% auto;`  ?

Answer (score 1):

Add following style to your code to avoid repeating the image:

```
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you applied it as background you can use this property to avoid double occurrence in higher resolution

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

even you can mention all it in a single line like

```
background: #fff url('pic.jpg') no-repeat center center;
```

and if you want to stretch the image, then

```
background-size: 100% auto;
```

Comment: Hi Aravind,
This helped but now the background img is zoomed in. Do you know how to fix this problem?

Comment: @zenubeh you need a an image with better resolution (width and height) that only can solve it

Comment: I fixed it with this code:

background: url(pic.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 

Thx for your hint!

Comment: @zenubeh one note, if you used fixed, it has the chance that it won't work in mobile..double check it before using. and if it helped, accept it as answer..thanks!

Comment: @zenubeh your issues got fixed?

Comment: Yes the problem is fixed

Comment: If my answer helped, upvote and accept so it will be helpful for others who are looking for same type of questions..thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
  background: url(pic.jpg); 
  background-size: cover;  
  background-position: center;
  font-family: Lato;
  color: white;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

and you can reduce code by using

```
background: url('pic.jpg') no-repeat cover center;
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could solve your problem:

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: url('PATH_TO_IMG');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

You can see an example here https://codepen.io/Nacorga/pen/mjmBLp